# Can Windows Authenticate Against ApacheDS?

Tags: ldap, kerberos, apache-ds

ApacheDS claims to have support for ldap and Kerberos, so is it possible to authenticate Windows machines using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not out of the box. You can install the MIT kerberos client for Windows and you can run kinit against the KDC and you can probably map the local workstation user to the kerberos principal on the apache-ds database, but it is in not AD (which is what the Windows native kerberos client expects).

If you want to use kerberos with Windows clients you really need to use their implementation (you can get away with the samba 4 though).

By the way, authenticating Windows hosts against it (I suppose that is not what you meant, but it is, strictly taken, what you ask) is I think not possible. You could kerberize services running in them (like apache for instance), joining machines to the kerberos realm will be not possible.